# What is the nearest equivalent of :type in ghci in a ghc source file?

Tags: debugging, haskell, types

If I want to compare types or just print type information in a Haskell source file, what options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A handy trick I've recently discovered is to use typed holes in combination with `asTypeOf`<sup>1</sup>.

If you have code that *does* compile, and you want to know what the type of an expression within it is, replacing that expression with a hole sometimes messes things up, as in:

```
           -- what is the type of this part, I wonder?
f xs = 3 * length xs
```

Replacing `length xs` with a `_` reports:

```
foo.hs:1:12: Warning:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: a
    Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the inferred type of f :: t -> a at foo.hs:1:1
```

`length xs` is certainly not of type `a`!

But if you use `asTypeOf`, you can leave the `length xs` there *and* insert a hole which has to have the same type as it:

```
f xs = 3 * (length xs `asTypeOf` _)
```

Now we get:

```
foo.hs:1:34: Warning:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: Int
```

Much better.

---

<sup>1</sup> `asTypeOf` is exactly the same as `const`, in that it returns its first argument and completely ignores its second. However its type forces the second argument to be the same as the first; it's designed to be written infix with backticks.

It's designed for when you have an a sub-expression that's too polymorphic and GHC complains about ambiguous type variables; you could use an inline type declaration, but sometimes that's impossible without the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. If you have another value that is the correct type, you can use `asTypeOf` to "select" the appropriate case from the polymorphic expression, without changing the value returned by the expression.

My use of it here is "backwards" from the intended case; I want the thing on the left to constrain type of the (ignored) hole on the right, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

[Typed holes!](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes)

```
foo x =  length [x] + _
```

Compiling with GHC or loading into GHCi will give:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: Int
Relevant bindings include
  x :: a
  foo :: a -> Int
```